# make sure that no more than x items will be inserted

Tags: c#, .net, rest, distributed

Let's say that I have REST API app and I enable inserting through it some items to database, I would like to make sure that a lot of people at the same time can call that REST API to insert some objects but I also want to be sure that there will never be inserted more than x items of given type.

What would be optimal strategy for that? Let's say that there are 2 options, app is hosted only on a single node and second option is that it is distributed and can have multiple nodes on different servers but with the same database.

If it is hosted on one machine then I assume that I can have shared semaphore, easy but requests will be blocking each other all the time.

On distributed option I assume that there would have to be transaction od db level but how it could look like if performance is inportant?

I assume that this is generic and problem of well known class of problems so maybe you can give me any hints where can I read about it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think you could probably use database transactions and check the number of items each time before inserting.

Comment: *I also want to be sure that there will never be inserted more then x items of given type.* You mean within a given timeframe, or is it a hard limit?

Comment: it would be hard limit

Comment: @ADyson ok but how then this transaction would look like? Wouldn't it always block for read and write then the whole table at the begining of the transaction?

Comment: Generally transactions are very fast to do something like you're proposing, even if blocking occurs. It shouldn't stop you reading data at the same time, btw. exact implementations can vary by DBMS so you can read online more about how exactly transactions work in your chosen database system, what options you can choose and what impact they have. Also you didn't really say exactly what the volume of data you're talking about or the likely frequency of inserts. That can have an impact on the type of design and architecture you use.